# Encrypt/decrypt caesar cipher to file text

Tags: python

I've been stuck for days and can't find a way to encrypt/decrypt this in my text file.

I am supposed to use caesar cipher method(but not ROT 13). I just can't get it to work no matter what I do. All the methods I find I have to write a text to encrypt it, but I want it to my text file (`section1.priv.txt`).

Can anyone help me?

```
class customer(object):
    def __init__(self,title, name, birth, country_of_birth, gender,    working_status, nationality,c_residence, tax_res,
        relation_ship_customer,phone_number,address,moved_in):
        self.title = title
        self.name = name
        self.birth = birth
        self.country_of_birth = country_of_birth
        self.gender = gender
        self.working_status = working_status
        self.nationality = nationality
        self.c_residence = c_residence
        self.tax_res = tax_res
        self.relation_ship_customer = relation_ship_customer
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.address = address
        self.moved_in = moved_in

    def customer_1_info(self):
      f=open("section1.priv.txt","a")
      f.write("CUSTOMER 1 INFO: "+"\n")
      f.write("Fullname: " + self.title + " " + self.name + "\n" + "Birth DD/MM/YY:v" + self.birth+"\n"
      + "Country and town of birth: "+self.country_of_birth
      +"\n"+ "Gender:" + self.gender +"\n"+ "Working Status: " + self.working_status+"\n" +"Nationality: "
      + self.nationality
      +"\n"+ "Country Residence: " + self.c_residence
      +"\n"+ "Tax Country Resident: " + self.tax_res + "\n"+ "Relationship to customer 2:"+self.relation_ship_customer+"\n")
      f.write("\n")
      f.write("CONTACT AND RESIDENTIAL DETAILS:"+"\n")
      f.write("Phone numbers(Mobile,home,work): "+self.phone_number+"\n"+"Address: "+self.address+"\n"
      +"Date moved in: "+self.moved_in+"\n")
      f.write("\n")
      f.close()

    def customer_2_info(self):
      f=open("section1.priv.txt","a")
      f.write("CUSTOMER 2 INFO: "+"\n")
      f.write("Fullname: " + self.title + " " + self.name + "\n" + "Birth DD/MM/YY: " + self.birth+"\n"
      + "Country and town of birth: "+self.country_of_birth
      +"\n"+ "Gender:" + self.gender +"\n"+ "Working Status: "+self.working_status +"\n"+ "Nationality: " + self.nationality +"\n"
      +"Country Residence: " + self.c_residence
      +"\n"+ "Tax Country Resident: " + self.tax_res +"\n"+"Relationship to customer 1: "+self.relation_ship_customer+"\n")
      f.write("\n")
      f.write("CONTACT AND RESIDENTIAL DETAILS:" + "\n")
      f.write("Phone numbers(Mobile,home,work): " + self.phone_number + "\n" + "Address: " + self.address + "\n"
      + "Date moved in: " + self.moved_in)
      f.write("\n")
      f.close()

p1 = customer(input("Mr, Mrs, Miss, Ms:"),
input("Fullname:"),
input("Birth DD/MM/YY:"),
input("Country and town of birth:"),
input("Female/male:"),
input("""Working status: Employed,Self Employed,Part Time,Unemployed(YY/MM), Not Working,Seeking Work, Retired, Student,Other(Explain)
Please WRITE status:"""),
input("Nationality: "),
input("Country Residence:"),
input("Tax Country Resident:"),
input("Relationship to customer 2:"),
input("Phone numbers(mobile,home,work:)"),
input("Full address(postcode,country):"),
input("Date moved in(MM/YYYY):"+"\n"))

p2 = customer(input("Mr, Mrs, Miss, Ms:"),
input("Fullname:"),
input("Birth DD/MM/YY:"),
input("Country and town of birth:"),
input("Female/male:"),
input("""Working status: Employed,Self Employed,
Part Time,Unemployed(YY/MM),Not Working,Seeking Work,   Retired,Student,Other(Explain)
Please write status:"""),
input("Nationality:"),
input("Country Residence:"),
input("Tax Country Resident:"),
input("Relationship to customer 1:"),
input("Phone numbers(mobile,home,work:"),
input("Full address(postcode,country:"),
input("Date moved in(MM/YYYY):"))

p1.customer_1_info()
p2.customer_1_info()
```

Comment: Please 1) read about how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this is far too much code to debug, and 2) format (indent) your code properly.

Comment: You will have to give more information. What happens when you run your code? What should happend and doesn't? Any error message (add the full error traceback to your question)?

Comment: Nothing happens. I also tried adding this code : with open("section1.priv.txt") as f: print(f.read().translate(str.maketrans(ascii_uppercase[ROTATE:]
+ascii_uppercase[:ROTATE]+ascii_lowercase[ROTATE:]+ascii_lowercase[:ROTATE], ascii_uppercase+ascii_lowercase)))   but then it only print out the encrypted in the terminal but that's not where I want it. I want it in my text file named "section1.priv.txt